# Is it possible to set up an event listener that will catch all ERC20 tokens

Tags: erc-20, events

Is it possible to set up an event listener in such a way that it will trigger for all token transfers?

I am using web3.rs at the moment which is an implementation of web3.js in Rust. So anything that will work in Web3.js would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so much sure about using web3.rs, but if you are open to another solution, I know Moralis provide such a solution.

Moralis have Streams API that can be used to listen to emitted events on EVM chains and you can listen to all ERC20 token transfers on the preferred chain(s).

You can follow their existing tutorial for that [here](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/how-to-listen-to-all-erc20-contract-transfers-over-certain-amount-sent-by-specific-address). If you don't like to listen to only transfer above a certain amount or have specific sender or receiver, then you can feel free to delete the `advancedOptions` field in the input.

Hope this helps!